# mysqli count user actions and print results

Tags: mysqli, count

Im trying to print the user name and the number of times it was found but i cant seem to get the count to show! I have looked and cant seem to find out how.

```
$sql = "SELECT user, COUNT(user)
FROM user_stats
GROUP BY user";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  $user = $row['user'];

  $count = $row['count'];

  echo $user 

  echo $count; 
}
```

Im looking to get

User1 2

User2 3

from a database that is like this

USER

User1

User1

User2

User2

User2

Thanks in advance sorry if its simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now was simple to do

$count = $row['COUNT(user)'];